# Houve vs houveram. Como utilizar corretamente?

Tags: ortografia

Tenho uma dúvida em relação ao uso das palavras "houve" e "houveram". É uma questão de uso no plural ou existe alguma regra específica para o uso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resumo**

Quando o verbo haver for empregado com sentido de "existir" ou "acontecer", ele deve ser conjugado na terceira pessoa do singular, nesse caso, *houve*.

Quando ele não for empregado com esses sentidos, use *houve* se o sujeito for singular e *houveram* se o sujeito for plural.

**Resposta detalhada**

Os [verbos impessoais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbo_impessoal) são conjugados apenas na 3ª pessoa do singular, independente dos outros elementos da frase estarem no plural ou no singular.

Por isso dizemos "Choveu muito nas últimas noites" ao invés de "choveram".

Uma vez entendido isto, para escolher entre "houve" e "houveram", ou "havia" e "haviam", etc, basta determinar se na frase avaliada o verbo haver tem papel impessoal. E isso bem fácil. Em geral, haver é impessoal se significar existir ou acontecer e pessoal quando usado como auxiliar.

Por exemplo,

*Há vários eleitores indecisos.* (Equivalente a existem, logo, impessoal, por isso, no singular).

*Nesta pista houve alguns acidentes.* (Equivale a aconteceram, logo, impessoal, portanto, no singular).

Já nos exemplos seguintes, o verbo haver é usado como auxiliar, por isso, aceita todas as conjugações (normalmente, pode-se substituí-lo por "ter" nestes casos).

*Maria **havia** enviado o projeto ao congresso.*

*Maria e Ana **haviam** enviado o projeto ao congresso.*

Comment: O impessoal nem sempre é tão óbvio....

Comment: Simplesmente adicionar: "Maria houve de enviar o projeto ao congresso." e "Maria e Ana houveram de enviar o projeto ao congresso.". *Houveram* só ocorre quando **haver** tem sentido de ter/precisar — em todos os casos que posso imaginar.

Answer (score 1):

O verbo haver no sentido de existir ou de acontecimento fica na 3 pessoa do singular.
Exemplo .:  havia varias pessoas na casa de seu zé.
           Existia varias pessoas na casa de seu zé.

Note que O verbo haver é  impessoal e não admite sujeito.